# Как сделать сайт, где главная страница написана на html css, а остальные на cms Wordperss

Tags: html, css, wordpress, cms

Надо сделать так, чтобы главная страница была написана вручную, и не была связана с вордпресс, а остальные принадлежали этой cms. При этом все файлы страниц находятся в одной директории

Comment: Только один вопрос: зачем вам это извращение? ))

Comment: почему бы в файл шаблона front-page.php не вставить чистый html? Результат будет тот же

Answer (score 0):

Требуется создать `index.html` в корне, в настройках сервера  задать ее как первую индексную (главную) страницу.

В *ISPmanager* это делается в настройках сайта:

[image]

Или редирект через `.htaccess`:

```
Redirect 301 /index.php http://www.site.ru/index.html
```